# Why is my list comprehension only grabbing 0s?

Tags: python

LINE 11: List comprehension is only getting 0s?

please answer with the solution and nothing unrelated.

```
SUM_OF_DIVISORS = 0     # SUM OF THE DIVISORS OF (N)

def DIVISORS_SUM(N = 0):
    global SUM_OF_DIVISORS
    SUM_OF_DIVISORS -= N # MAKING SURE THAT N ITSELF IS EXCLUDED

    if N != 0:
        NUMBER = N

    try:
        DIVISORS = [X for X in range(0, N) if X%NUMBER == 0] # LIST COMPREHENSION (QUICK WAY OF FINDING DIVISORS)
        
        X: int
        for X in DIVISORS: # CREATING A FOR LOOP TO ADD TO SUM.
            SUM_OF_DIVISORS += X
        print(SUM_OF_DIVISORS)
    except:
        print("CAN'T CREATE SUM OF DIVISORS WITH 0.")

DIVISORS_SUM(0) # RETURNS ERROR BECAUSE N ITSELF MUST BE EXCLUDED
DIVISORS_SUM(3) # RETURNS 1 BECAUSE SUM OF DIVISORS WITH N EXCLUDED ADDS UP TO 1
DIVISORS_SUM(36) # RETURNS 36 BECAUSE SUM OF DIVISORS WITH N EXCLUDED ADDS UP TO 1
DIVISORS_SUM(102) # RETURNS 102 BECAUSE SUM OF DIVISORS WITH N EXCLUDED ADDS UP TO 1
```

Comment: You probably mixed up the order and want: `if NUMBER % X == 0`. But you should use `range(1, N)` to avoid dividing by zero.

Comment: What values do you expect `range(0, N)` to contain? For example, what do you expect to see if you run `print(list(range(0, 5)))`? Now, test it. Did it meet your expectation? Now, think about the logic. Should you be `# MAKING SURE THAT N ITSELF IS EXCLUDED`?

Comment: When you do `DIVISORS_SUM(3)`: `NUMBER` is `3`. `X = range(0, N)` goes from 0 to 2. Zero is the only number in this range for which `X % 3` is zero. [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953)

Comment: By the way, there is a built-in `sum` that you can feed the list comprehension to directly.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

`DIVISORS = [X for X in range(0, N) if X%NUMBER == 0]`

to:

`DIVISORS = [X for X in range(1, N) if (NUMBER % X) == 0]`

Note the `1` not zero to avoid `ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero`

Comment: can you please post the expected outputs for your examples

Comment: I see your comment, but why does DIVISORS_SUM(36) equal 36? Shouldn't it be 55 since `[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 12, 18]` are the DIVISORS

Comment: yeah I did I mistake

Comment: ok can you update your post to have the correct outputs for each example